# Read SQLite problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

I have NSTableView with two columns, and i wanna fill them entries from SQLite database.

this method is make query for table

```
-(void)getPersons
{

    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"persons" ofType:@"db"];
    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"i open database");
        sqlite3_exec(database, "select name,age from persons", MyCallback, persons, NULL);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

the problem appers in MyCallback method:

```
static int MyCallback(void *context, int count, char **values, char **columns)
{
    NSMutableArray *persons = (NSMutableArray *)context;

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {

        NSString *columnname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:columns[i]];
        const char *nameCString = values[i];

            if ([columnname isEqualTo:@"name"]) {
                [persons addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameCString]];
            }
        else {
            [ages addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameCString]];
        }

    }
    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

how can i write "age" entries into NSMutableArray *ages, if i can assign *context just for one NSMutableArray? (in this code, this is NSMutableArray *person)

Surely i should create a separate method for get age entries?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you need those in 2 separate arrays? Just create an `NSObject` subclass with a name and age property (even more probably), and add instances of that subclass to just one `NSMutableArray`. Then you don't have to mess around with all these problems.

Comment: maybe you have a little example project?

Comment: cru3l: What JoostK is talking about is called a model object. Apple has a guide to making them: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/ A parallel array, which is what your code is trying to create, is almost always the wrong way to do something in Cocoa, and in this case, it turns out to be the wrong way to do it in SQLite as well.

Comment: Also, use a SQLite wrapper, like FMDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many **simple cases** like the one in your question it is convinient use most natural representation of tables in objective-c: array of dictionaries. Table is indexed collection of records - so it is an array, and each record is collection of key-value pairs - so it is a dictionary. And you need not change you code when you change column names or even number of colums.

```
...
NSMutableArray *allRecords= (NSMutableArray *)context;
NSString *columnName;
NSString *columnValue;
NSMutableDictionary * record = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
  columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:columns[i]];
  if (values[i]){
    columnValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:values[i]];
  }
  else{
    columnValue = @"";
  }
  [record setObject:columnValue forKey:columnName]; 
}
[allRecords addObject:record];
...
```